# Bootstrap 4 - NavBar Fixo com BackGround White

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav-bar, layout-responsivo

Fala galera estou com problemas pois nao consigo deixar minha NavBar com fundo branco quando ela passar de 400px pra baixo. Quero ela transparente no inico e depois de 400px ela ficar com um fundo branco.Ps: Quero editar o navbar quando conseguir fazer isso. Segue o codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Titulo.</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all-animation.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="caminhodoarquivo/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
<style>
 bg-darl.scrolled(TENTEI FAZER ISSO MAS N DEU) {
  background-color:white !important;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="mynavbar">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a href="indexpadrao.html" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria- 
controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna 
navegação">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="plans.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">Sobre</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item pr-2">
           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">Portifolio</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline- 
 light">Contato</button>
       </li>     
   </ul>                  
</div>      
</nav>
<div class="principal2">
 <h1 class="display-1">Meu Nome é Matheus Luiz.</h1>
   <hr>
    <h3 class="display-1">Sejam Bem-Vindos e conheçam um pouco do meu 
trabalho.</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg display-1" 
 style="padding-left:30px;padding-right: 30px;font-size:1.8rem">Saiba 
  mais</button>
     </div> 
</div>
 <!-- Primeiro o jsquery -->
 <!-- Segundo o Popper min -->
 <!-- Terceiro o Bootstrap js -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/our.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled',$(this).scrollTop() > 400);
      });

</script>
 </body>  
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código está certo, apenas o seletor está errado: esse `bg-darl` não existe.

Você deveria usar `nav.scrolled`.

Veja:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled',$(this).scrollTop() > 400);
});
```

```css
nav.scrolled{
  background-color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="mynavbar">
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a href="indexpadrao.html" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="images/logo.png">
</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria- 
controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna 
navegação">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="conteudoNavbarSuportado">
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="plans.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">Sobre</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item pr-2">
           <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">Portifolio</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline- 
 light">Contato</button>
       </li>     
   </ul>                  
</div>      
</nav>
<div class="principal2">
 <h1 class="display-1">Meu Nome é Matheus Luiz.</h1>
   <hr>
    <h3 class="display-1">Sejam Bem-Vindos e conheçam um pouco do meu 
trabalho.</h3>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg display-1" 
 style="padding-left:30px;padding-right: 30px;font-size:1.8rem">Saiba 
  mais</button>
     </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Beleza mano, ajudou demais so mais uma duvidazinha. Eu preciso mudar o logo e as cores do da fonte do navbar. Onde eu posso fazer isso? Coloquei .scrollTop() > 200); Ai quando aparece o bg branco eu preciso mudar o logo e as cor da fonte. Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Blz. Só não deixe de marcar ✔️ na resposta se ela resolveu o problema. Para alterar a logo vc pode fazer o seguinte: coloque duas tags <img> com as duas logos, sendo que uma ficará com display: none antes dos 200px... aí quando alcançar os 200px vc esconde a primeira e mostra a segunda, e vice-versa. Para alterar a cor a mesma coisa. Adicione na classe .scrolled a cor que vc quer: ex., `color: red;`